# Populate DE after send with Job info

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, field-update, dataextensions, automationstudio

I am currently working with **Data Extensions (DE) and Queries inside the Exactarget web platform**. 
I have a DE (let´s call it **Input-DE**) which is updated daily with new **emails** and some other infos (let´s say fields **A**, **B**). 
I created an automation to daily send a predefined html to these emails. 
After the send I want to populate another DE (let´s call it **send-DE**), with info such as **email**, fields **A** and **B**, and also **date of send** and **Job ID**. 
The first three I can easily do just by using **input-DE** to populate **send-DE**, the hard part for me now is the **Date of send** and **Job ID**. 
I figured I could create the **Date of send** field in the DE with the default value of **current date** which would give a date a few seconds after the actual send (not a problem since I would like to keep an eye just on the day of the actual send). 
Anyone got any better ideas on how to populate  **Job ID** (`more importantly`) and **Date of send**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the "Send Logging" option for your sends.  Below link has some further info on this feature.

What this does is write a row to the Send Log DE for each subscriber you are sending to; it also allows you to define variables/fields to also pass back specific data along with that standard fields that you've added.

[Send Logging Information](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/send_logging/)

Comment: It will also record Profile Attributes and Personalization string values.

Comment: Also Send Logging has to be enabled by SFMC Support.

Comment: `Date of Send` (and other information) can be retrieved via Query Activity, joining back to the `_Job` [System Data View](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/) by `JobID`